# How do I resolve the parse utils import error that occurs when uploading the application?

Tags: javascript, angular

I came across the following error when executing *ng serve -o*.

```
8 import { ParseSourceSpan } from '../parse_util';                                         
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/app.module.ts:17:12 - error NG1010: Value at position 4 in the NgModule.imports of AppModule is not a reference
  Value could not be determined statically.

 17   imports: [
               ~
 18     BrowserModule,
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
 22     ParseSourceSpan
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 23   ],
    ~~~

  src/app/app.module.ts:22:5
    22     ParseSourceSpan
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Unknown reference.
```

---

My **app.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

import { ParseSourceSpan } from 'parse-utils';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    ParseSourceSpan
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You import path seems to be incorrect It should be './parse_util'; if they are in the same directory. Else install a plugin called Auto-import in visual studio code. it helps resolve the imports.

Comment: I'm actually including parse-utils because my application requested it.

If I start the application without importing parse-utils, the following error occurs:


Error: ../node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/i18n/i18n_ast.d.ts:8:33 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../parse_util' or its corresponding type declarations.

8 import { ParseSourceSpan } from '../parse_util';

So I did the import using './parse-utils' even so it didn't work.

Comment: Install auto import extension and type ParseSourceSpan, then press Ctrl+Space and it gives you a list of imports available for that particular item, Try this and it will sort out the problem.

Comment: I imported it by extension 'import {ParseSourceSpan} from '@ angular / compiler';'

However I still have the errors:
Error: ../node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/i18n/i18n_ast.d.ts:8:33 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../parse_util' or its corresponding type declarations.
8 import {ParseSourceSpan} from '../parse_util';
Error: node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/parse_util.d.ts: 20: 22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

Comment: Remove this from the imports array on the NgModule. Because this is not an NgModule. Also try deleting your node_modules folder after that and run `npm install` again